# infinite loop a set of images

Tags: javascript, jquery

This doesn't work quite well when it reached the last image, I have to click twice to go back to the first image.

```
var i = 1;
$('.rightArrow').click(function () {
    if(i != 4) {
        $('body').css(
            'background',
            'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)), url("'+
                customerBgs[i]+'") no-repeat center center fixed'
        );
        i++;
    }else{
        i = 0;
        $('body').css(
            'background',
            'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)), url("'+
                customerBgs[i]+'") no-repeat center center fixed'
        );

    }
});
```

Comment: no need to completely duplicate `$('body'),css()` code, just change `i`. Learn to use browser console to inspect variable values and you won't be guessing so much why things aren't working as expected

Comment: As you click, what values does `i` take on? This code looks ok to me - `i` should go through this sequence: `1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2` etc. On a side note, your `$('body').css(...)` call can be outside the `if` - it'll make your code a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not something even more simple

```
var i = 0;
var customerBgs = ['http://placehold.it/350x150', 'http://placehold.it/500x100', 'http://placehold.it/100x510', 'http://placehold.it/300x500'];
$('.rightArrow').click(function() {
    $('body').css(
        'background',
        'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)), url("' + customerBgs[i] + '") no-repeat center center fixed');
    i = ++i % customerBgs.length;
});
```

DEMO below

```js
var i = 0;
var customerBgs = ['http://placehold.it/350x150', 'http://placehold.it/500x100', 'http://placehold.it/100x510', 'http://placehold.it/300x500'];
$('.rightArrow').click(function () {
    $('body').css(
        'background',
        'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)), url("' + customerBgs[i] + '") no-repeat center center fixed');
    i = ++i % customerBgs.length;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="rightArrow" type="button" value="right" />
```

Comment: the problem with this is I can't fade in the background

Comment: Probably just a personal preference, but I feel that `i = ++i % customerBgs.length` is a bit ugly, as you're assigning `i` twice. For me, `i = (i + 1) % customerBgs.length` is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume customerBgs start from 0

```
var i = 0;
$('.rightArrow').click(function(){
    i++;
    if (i > customerBgs.length - 1) {
        i = 0;
    }
    $('body').css(
        'background',
        'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)), url("'+
            customerBgs[i]+'") no-repeat center center fixed'
    );
});
```

Comment: the problem with this is I can't fade in the background, right? the body got faded which is not nice

Answer (score 0):

You're not incrementing i in your else block, so it resets to image 0, then goes through the process of setting the background again before moving on to image 1.  You could probably, however, pull the incrementing out of the if case and just check to see if you need to wrap around to 0 before setting the background.  This would keep you from having to duplicate the background setting in both blocks.